# Area around thw screw of our new toddler bed broke off, shows black blotches inside! Is this harmful or just iron staining? Please help

Tags: mold, furniture, bedroom

We just recently got a toddler bed and while assembling, a chunk of wood fell off and showed black discoloration inside near the screw area. Is this normal or is this harmful? I am worried since my son will certainly jump on the bed, will this staining make the wood weaker and break the bed and fall off on the toddler? Please help, I am an amateur when it comes to this and would like to be very sure before proceeding to build the bed.

[image]

Comment: No, it is not normal

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say it happened during manufacturing, something was not drilled properly. Check if you have a warranty.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to asses the situation with a single pic and no reference location.  However being the bed is new and that black looks like a degradation,
I would return the bed. It appears to have a defect.